# Changing charset from latin2_bin to utf8 and back erased all data that starts with "special" character

Tags: mysql, sql, character-encoding

I changed charset from latin2_bin to utf8 in one of the columns in my table to fix sorting problem. It didin't hwlp and in addition to that, when i switched back to latin2_bin all records have same bug

```
łokacinski -> empty
środek -> empty
ośrodek -> o
czółko -> cz
```

so if the surname start with special(polish) character it's been completly deleted and if the special character is in the middle, i ve got only characters before special character.
I didint think something so silly would erase that much data... Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

You used the wrong conversion technique.

Here is a list of typical issues, and fixes for each http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases

For further help, please provide `SELECT HEX(col), ...` as mentioned in [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) .

"Erased" sounds like the "truncated" case that I discuss.  Please provide an example.

Comment: I tried to HEX it and it showed empty data. So it really somehow erased data. Lucky for me, i found backup from 2 days before, so im saved.

Comment: One of the scenarios "truncates" the data, thereby losing text.